# How do I delete all my mail from the inbox in ProtonMail?

Tags: protonmail

When using ProtonMail, there doesn't seem to be a way to delete all my mail in my inbox. I have over 10K+ emails that I just want to archive. Currently I have to select one at a time to move them to archive. Is there an easier way to move all of it to archive?

Comment: There is a select all checkbox in protonmail. Isn't it working?

Comment: @SeverusSnape I'm having the same problem. The checkbox only selects all the emails on the current page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified the previous answer which left out the next page click to:

```
const a = setInterval( function () {
  document.querySelector("#idSelectAll").click() ; 
  document.querySelector("button[data-testid='toolbar:movetotrash']").click() ;
  document.querySelector("button[data-testid='toolbar:next-page']").click()
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same issue, and wrote a script working in 2021 consisting of a line of JavaScript selecting emails and clicking on the trash button, then going to next page.
run this in your JS console (f12 for Firefox) after having enabled the ability to copy paste.

`const a = setInterval( function () { document.querySelector("#idSelectAll").click() ; document.querySelector("button[data-testid='toolbar:movetotrash']").click() }, 2000);`

to stop the script to run, cancel the interval in the a variable:

```
clearInterval(a);
```

just tried today, it works.
After, go to your trash folder, and hit the 3 dots options, "erase all" for this folder.

Comment: you are GOD-LIKE